# How can I batch several Python package installers?

Tags: python, installation

I want to have users install Python and several packages generated using distutil's bdist_wininst option (`python setup.py bdist_wininst`).  Are there command-line options for the installers so I can batch them all together? None of `/help`, `/?`, `--help`, `-h` turn up any useful information, nor the [build instructions](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-windows-installers) on Python's docs.

In absence of any command-line switches on the installers, what are some alternatives to distribute Python with a bunch of packages? Canopy seems interesting, but it lacks a few essentials.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have python installed, you can use it to install the required components. Start simple and build:

```
import subprocess
pkgs = ['ipaddr', 'sqlalchemy', 'ipython',]

for pkg in pkgs:
    subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', pkg])
```

Comment: pip is great, but C/Python packages will require the compilation environment, e.g. VS2008/2010, as well as the libraries and headers. My goal is to skip all that and just go with binaries for Windows users.

Comment: Roger.  Switch from pip to easy_install. No compilation required (usually)